# Error 100 with dpkg

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates, dpkg

I'm a newbie migrating from Windows coding to Ubuntu, but once I logged onto my machine there was this error with dpkg which is preventing me from installing any packages. I might have messed up while installing previous packages and etc.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 btw.

```
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
    root@lucas-G750JX:~# apt-get -f install
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Correcting dependencies... Done
    The following extra packages will be installed:
      dpkg update-notifier update-notifier-common
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      dpkg
    The following packages will be upgraded:
      update-notifier update-notifier-common
    2 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
            Need to get 0 B/2.297 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 6.770 kB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    Could not exec dpkg!
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)
```

Tried to imput ls -l /usr/bin/

```
   root@lucas-G750JX:~# ls -l /usr/bin/dpkg
   ls: cannot access /usr/bin/dpkg: No such file or directory
```

Any tip on how to solve this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of command `ls -l /usr/bin/dpkg`. What were you doing recently that you think may have messed up?

Comment: I was trying to solve the problem "No such file or directory". On the forums I learned (or I think that I learned) that this problem happens due to the fact that my Ubuntu is a 64 bit version trying to run 32 bit stuff... So I tried to install the i386 libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system lacks the essential package and program `dpkg`. Usually one would install missing packages with the package manager, but unfortunately `dpkg` *is* the package manager.

Considering that you seem to just have installed Ubuntu, I recommend that you re-install it, because that will be a lot easier than bootstrapping the package manager on the botched system.